# String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

In my application i'm attempting to take a StringBuffer filled with all of my Contacts info and post it to a php server using JSON.

Here is the code I'm working with

```
public void printBuffer(Context context) {
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    output = fetchContacts(context);
//  Log.i("MyMessage", output.toString());
    sendContacts(output);
}

private void sendContacts(StringBuffer sb) {
    try {
        JSONObject toSend = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

        JSONTransmitter transmitter = new JSONTransmitter();
        transmitter.execute(new JSONObject[] {toSend});


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

For some reason when the code executes and I'm looking to get a response from the server in LogCat, instead I see the following warnings:

```
05-26 01:55:40.383: W/System.err(22683): org.json.JSONException: Value First of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
05-26 01:55:40.393: W/System.err(22683):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
05-26 01:55:40.393: W/System.err(22683):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
05-26 01:55:40.393: W/System.err(22683):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
05-26 01:55:40.393: W/System.err(22683):    at com.remoteware.gcm.Contact.sendContacts(Contact.java:28)
```

Does anyone know what this error means/how I could go about fixing it?

Here is my JSONTransmitter class for reference just in case:

```
public class JSONTransmitter extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject> {


String url = "http://myphpserver/json.php";

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... data) {                
    JSONObject json = data[0];
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 100000);

    JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity("json="+json.toString());
        post.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        post.setEntity(se);

        HttpResponse response;
        response = client.execute(post);
        String resFromServer = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.i("Server response: ", resFromServer);
        jsonResponse=new JSONObject(resFromServer);
        Log.i("Response from server", jsonResponse.getString("msg"));
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}

    return jsonResponse;
}


}
```

Comment: can you print your json string and post it here?

Comment: this is the output of sb.toString(): 05-26 18:44:24.805: I/MyMessage(3463):  First Name:AT&T Check Bill Balance
05-26 18:44:24.805: I/MyMessage(3463):  Phone number:*225#
05-26 18:44:24.805: I/MyMessage(3463):  First Name:AT&T Customer Care
05-26 18:44:24.805: I/MyMessage(3463):  Phone number:1-800-331-0500
05-26 18:44:24.805: I/MyMessage(3463):  First Name:AT&T Directory Assistance
05-26 18:44:24.805: I/MyMessage(3463):  Phone number:411
05-26 18:44:24.805: I/MyMessage(3463):  First Name:AT&T Pay My Bill
05-26 18:44:24.805: I/MyMessage(3463):  Phone number:*729
...

Comment: This doesn't seem to be JSON. I think you missed something with the `HttpResponse`, in your `AsyncTask`, the in put is `JSONObject`, where does it come from?

Comment: Should I try to use GSON to parse the String before I put it in? This confuses me because    [code]JSONObject toSend = new JSONObject();
   toSend.put("msg", "hello");
            JSONTransmitter transmitter = new JSONTransmitter();
            transmitter.execute(new JSONObject[] {toSend}); [/code] works just fine

Comment: And the PHP server replies using an encoded JSON message. PHP Code is as follows: '<?php
 
if( isset($_POST["json"]) ) {  
     $data = json_decode($_POST["json"]);  
     $data->msg = $data;
     echo json_encode($data);
 
}
'